# Copy pandas DataFrame row to multiple other rows

Tags: python, pandas

Simple and practical question, yet I can't find a solution.

The questions I took a look were the following:

[Modifying a subset of rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307099/modifying-a-subset-of-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

[Changing certain values in multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867734/changing-certain-values-in-multiple-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-at-once)

[Fastest way to copy columns from one DataFrame to another using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295329/fastest-way-to-copy-columns-from-one-dataframe-to-another-using-pandas)

[Selecting with complex criteria from pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe)

The key difference between those and mine is that I need not to insert a single value, but a row.

My problem is, I pick up a row of a dataframe, say `df1`. Thus I have a series.

Now I have this other dataframe, `df2`, that I have selected multiple rows according to a criteria, and I want to replicate that series to all those row.

df1:

```
Index/Col   A   B  C
1           0   0  0
2           0   0  0
3           1   2  3
4           0   0  0
```

df2:

```
Index/Col   A   B  C
1           0   0  0
2           0   0  0
3           0   0  0
4           0   0  0
```

What I want to accomplish is inserting df1[3] into the lines df2[2] and df3[3] for example. So something like the non working code:

```
series = df1[3]
df2[df2.index>=2 and df2.index<=3] = series
```

returning

df2:

```
Index/Col   A   B  C
1           0   0  0
2           1   2  3
3           1   2  3
4           0   0  0
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `loc` and pass a list of the index labels of interest, after the following comma the `:` indicates we want to set all column values, we then assign the series but call attribute `.values` so that it's a numpy array. Otherwise you will get a `ValueError` as there will be a shape mismatch as you're intending to overwrite 2 rows with a single row and if it's a `Series` then it won't align as you desire:

```
In [76]:
df2.loc[[2,3],:] = df1.loc[3].values
df2

Out[76]:
   A  B  C
1  0  0  0
2  1  2  3
3  1  2  3
4  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have to copy certain rows and columns from dataframe to some another data frame do this.
    `code`

```
    df2 = df.loc[x:y,a:b]   // x and y are rows bound and a and b are column 
                                bounds that you have to select
```