# Python Pandas Copy Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I copy multiple columns from one dataframe to a new dataframe? it would also be nice to rename them at the same time

```
df2['colA']=df1['col-a']  #This works

df2['colA', 'colB']=df1['col-a', 'col-b'] #Tried and Failed
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to copy columns from one DataFrame to another using pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295329/fastest-way-to-copy-columns-from-one-dataframe-to-another-using-pandas)

Answer (score 28):

You have to use double brackets:

```
df2[['colA', 'colB']] = df1[['col-a', 'col-b']]
```

Comment: Does that return already a copy or would one need `df1[['col-a', 'col-b']].copy()`?

Comment: @Cleb You don't need the copy as the view (?) of df1 is being assigned into the df2. It's not destructive, the view gets GCd afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

This is tried and tested for pandas=1.3.0 :

```
df2 = df1[['col-a', 'col-b']].copy()
```

If you also want to rename the column names at the same time, you can write:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['colA', 'colB'])
df2[['colA', 'colB']] = df1[['col-a', 'col-b']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Following also works:

```
# original DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['hello', 'cheerio', 'hi', 'bye'], 'b': [1, 0, 1, 0]})
# new DataFrame created from 2 original cols (new cols renamed)
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['greeting', 'mode'], data=df[['a','b']].values)
```

If you want to use condition for the new dataframe:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['farewell', 'mode'], data=df[df['b']==0][['a','b']].values)
```

Or if you want use just particular rows (index), you can use "loc":

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['greetings', 'mode'], data=df.loc[2:3][['a','b']].values)

# if you need preserve row index, then add index=... as argument, like:
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['farewell', 'mode'], data=df.loc[2:3][['a','b']].values, 
                      index=df.loc[2:3].index )
```

Answer (score 2):

As for Pandas=1.2.4, the easiest way would be:

```
df2[['colA', 'colB']] = df1[['col-a', 'col-b']].values
```

note that it doesn't require *.copy()* as applying *values* first converts dataframe values into a numpy array (shallow copy) and then copy values (link the address of array in the memory) into dataframe. Exactly the same as when you apply *copy()* at the end of it.